# JavaScript upload file max size

Tags: javascript, upload, filesize, datalife-engine

I have to upload the code
this code for Datalife engine. How do I make the file size limit ~5Mb. And where to put the code? Sorry I'm bad speaking English. Thanks for help.

```
    $allowed_extensions = array ("gif", "jpg", "png", "jpe", "jpeg" );
if ((isset($_FILES['post_add']) && $_FILES['post_add']!='')) {

    $file_prefix = time() + rand( 1, 100 );
    $file_prefix .= "_";
    define( 'FOLDER_PREFIX', date( "Y-m" ) );
if( ! is_dir( ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX ) ) {
    @mkdir( ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX, 0777 );
    @chmod( ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX, 0777 );
    @mkdir( ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX . "/thumbs", 0777 );
    @chmod( ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX . "/thumbs", 0777 );
}            
    $config_path_image_upload = ROOT_DIR . "/uploads/posts/" . FOLDER_PREFIX . "/";

    $current_image = 'post_add';
    $image = $_FILES[$current_image]['tmp_name'];
    $image_name = $_FILES[$current_image]['name'];
    $image_size = $_FILES[$current_image]['size'];
    $error_code = $_FILES[$current_image]['error'];

    $img_name_arr = explode( ".", $image_name );
    $type = totranslit( end( $img_name_arr ) );
    if( $image_name != "" ) {
        $curr_key = key( $img_name_arr );
        unset( $img_name_arr[$curr_key] );
        $image_name = totranslit( implode( ".", $img_name_arr ) ) . "." . $type;
    }

    if ( in_array( strtolower( $type ), $allowed_extensions) ) {

    @move_uploaded_file( $image, $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name );

    if( @file_exists( $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name ) ) {
        @chmod( $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name, 0666 );
            $row = $db->super_query( "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM " . PREFIX . "_images where author = '{$member_id[name]}' AND news_id = '$idpost'" );
            if( ! $row['count'] ) {
                $added_time = time() + ($config['date_adjust'] * 60);
                $inserts = FOLDER_PREFIX . "/" . $file_prefix . $image_name;
                $db->query( "INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "_images (images, author, news_id, date) values ('$inserts', '{$member_id[name]}', '$idpost', '$added_time')" );
            } else {
                $row = $db->super_query( "SELECT images  FROM " . PREFIX . "_images where author = '{$member_id[name]}' AND news_id = '$idpost'" );
                if( $row['images'] == "" ) $listimages = array ();
                else $listimages = explode( "|||", $row['images'] );
                foreach ( $listimages as $dataimages ) {
                    if( $dataimages == FOLDER_PREFIX . "/" . $file_prefix . $image_name ) $error_image = "stop";
                }
                if( $error_image != "stop" ) {
                    $listimages[] = FOLDER_PREFIX . "/" . $file_prefix . $image_name;
                    $row['images'] = implode( "|||", $listimages );
                    $db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_images set images='{$row['images']}' where author = '{$member_id[name]}' AND news_id = '$idpost'" );
                }
            }
        include_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/thumb.class.php';
        $tumb_ok = false;
        $_POST['make_thumb'] = true;
        $_POST['make_watermark'] = $config['allow_watermark'];
        if( isset( $_POST['make_thumb'] ) ) {
            $thumb = new thumbnail( $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name );
            if( $thumb->size_auto( $config['max_image'], $_POST['t_seite'] ) ) {
                $thumb->jpeg_quality( $config['jpeg_quality'] );
                if( $config['allow_watermark'] == "yes" and $_POST['make_watermark'] == "yes" ) $thumb->insert_watermark( $config['max_watermark'] );
                $thumb->save( $config_path_image_upload . "thumbs/" . $file_prefix . $image_name );
            }
            if( @file_exists( $config_path_image_upload . "thumbs/" . $file_prefix . $image_name ) ) $tumb_ok = true;
            @chmod( $config_path_image_upload . "thumbs/" . $file_prefix . $image_name, 0666 );
        }

        $config['max_up_side'] = intval( $config['max_up_side'] );
        if( ($config['allow_watermark'] == "yes" and $_POST['make_watermark'] == "yes") or $config['max_up_side'] ) {
            $thumb = new thumbnail( $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name );
            $thumb->jpeg_quality( $config['jpeg_quality'] );
            if( $config['max_up_side'] ) $thumb->size_auto( $config['max_up_side'] );
            if( $config['allow_watermark'] == "yes" and $_POST['make_watermark'] == "yes" ) $thumb->insert_watermark( $config['max_watermark'] );
            $thumb->save( $config_path_image_upload . $file_prefix . $image_name );
        }

        $short_story = preg_replace('/^<br \/>(.*?)(<br \/>)*?$/is', '$1', $short_story);
        if ( $tumb_ok ) $short_story = "<!--TBegin--><a href=\"{$config['http_home_url']}uploads/posts/".FOLDER_PREFIX."/{$file_prefix}{$image_name}\" onclick=\"return hs.expand(this)\" ><img align=\"left\" src=\"{$config['http_home_url']}uploads/posts/".FOLDER_PREFIX."/thumbs/{$file_prefix}{$image_name}\" alt='$title' title='$title'  /></a><!--TEnd-->".$short_story;
        else $short_story = "<img src=\"{$config['http_home_url']}uploads/posts/".FOLDER_PREFIX."/{$file_prefix}{$image_name}\" align=\"left\" alt='$title' title='$title' />".$short_story;
        $full_story = "<img src=\"{$config['http_home_url']}uploads/posts/".FOLDER_PREFIX."/{$file_prefix}{$image_name}\" align=\"center\" alt='$title' title='$title' />".$full_story;
        $short_story = addslashes($short_story);
        $full_story = addslashes($full_story);
        $db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_post SET short_story='$short_story', full_story='$full_story' where id = '$idpost'" );

    }
    }

}
```

I wrote to google translate

Comment: This is related to your web server settings, not Javascript options.

Comment: The amount of error suppression operators in your code is ridiculous.

Comment: and can be removed from the javascript server settings and make javascript help?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to play around with your code while you can set it in admin cp? the option can be set in system settings for both files and images, the new version of DLE settings are moved to Usergroup Manager